# Constraining other parameters usng fmincon MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

When using `fmincon` I constrain the values of two input parameters to be be in a given range, I then build a design matrix based on these values and use rdivide to calculate the beta parameters (i.e. the weights that provide the desired values for a given design matrix). I want to be able to constrain these `beta` values too. This is not part of the optimisation per se, but are values calculated from the parameters being optimised. Is there anyway to achieve this using `fmincon`?

```
clc



mats  = [1/12 3/12 6/12 9/12 1 15/12 18/12 21/12 24/12 30/12 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];
mats2=mats;




for ii = 1:size(rates_DL,1)

    for jj=1:10

        lam1=unifrnd(0,2.5);
        lam2=unifrnd(2.5,5.5);


        y2=rates_DL(ii,:);
        yc_m=rates_DL(ii,:);
        f=@(l)NSS_fmin(l,mats,mats2,y2,yc_m);

        L0=[lam1; lam2];
        lbn=[0 0];
        ubn=[30 30];


options=optimset('Algorithm','interior-point','Hessian','lbfgs','MaxFunEvals',10000,'TolFun',1e-16,'MaxIter',10000);
 [cn(:,ii,jj),residual(:,ii,jj),exitflag(:,ii,jj),output(:,ii,jj)]=fmincon(@(l)NSS_fmin(l,mats,mats2,y2,yc_m),L0,[],[],[],[],lbn,ubn,[],options);

end
```

end

This is how I have the problem set up now with the constraints on lam1 and lam2 only.

```
   function [residuals]=NSS_fmin(lambda,mats,mats2,y2,yc_m)

residuals=zeros(size(yc_m));

mats2=mats2';

nObs = size(y2,2);

G =  [ones(nObs,1),...
     (1-exp(-mats2/lambda(1)))./(mats2/lambda(1)),...
    ((1-exp(-mats2/lambda(1)))./(mats2/lambda(1)) - exp(-mats2/lambda(1))),...
    ((1-exp(-mats2/lambda(2)))./(mats2/lambda(2)) - exp(-mats2/lambda(2)))];

%betas = G\data.y2.';
betas = G\y2';

beta = vertcat(betas,lambda);

gam1 = mats/beta(5);
gam2 = mats/beta(6);
aux1 = 1-exp(-gam1);
aux2 = 1-exp(-gam2);

YC = beta(1) + ...
    beta(2)*(aux1./gam1) + ...
    beta(3)*(aux1./gam1+aux1-1) + ...
    beta(4)*(aux2./gam2+aux2-1);

residuals=YC-yc_m;

residuals=sum(residuals.^2);
```

end

As a work around I could test the values of the betas produced and if a violation occurred multiply residuals by Inf. However ideally I Would like to find a solution where I use the existing functionality within `fmincon`.

Comment: I'm not going to try to understand your code, but this sounds like something the `nonlcon` nonlinear constraint function argument to `fmincon` could be used for. And/or another common scheme is to append such parameters to your state vector so that they are part of your optimization. You then just have to do the work of pulling out the parts separately for each of the constraints. Nothing is simple.